# Проблема с программой c# и работой с файлами

Tags: c#

Я пишу программу для копирования файлов и последующее их удаление. Так же она отправляет их мне на почту, но неопределенное количество файлов(оно всегда разное) не может быть удаленно так как метод отправки который идет сразу перед методом удаления, как я понял, еще их использует, даже поставив паузу в выполнении кода на 2 минуты с помощью thread.sleep оно выдает то же самое, письмо с этими файлами дополнительно не приходит, значит они не грузятся в письмо и не отправляются, а файлы все еще заняты. Как это можно исправить? Если закомментировать метод отправки все работает, но если его вернуть все повторяется.

Если кратко, то у меня проблема в том что моя программа занимает случайную часть файлов из-за чего последний метод не может их удалить, хотя метод который к ним обращается, уже отработал, конкретно метод отправки файлов на почту.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу два решения:

1. простое, но "грязное": вы просто крутитесь в цикле до тех пор, пока удаление не сработает. Можно сделать небольшую паузу перед тем, как начинать "новый виток цикла". Хорошо бы вести список файлов, которые надо удалить, и "вычеркивать" из него те, которые уже удалили.
2. можно "заморочиться" и использовать [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0) . Он будет присылать вам уведомления при удалении каждого файла. Совместив это со списком файлов, вы получите нужную функциональность.

Но вообще, возможно, у Вас проблема в том, что при отправке остаются "хвосты": вы открываете файл для отправки, но не закрываете - что то в таком духе. С этим бороться можно также просто: попробуйте "отправку" запихнуть в директиву using{}: она всё сделает за вас. К сожалению, это - "диагноз, поставленный по аватарке": я ведь не видел Вашего кода.

> Ваш первый способ мне подходит, но я не понимаю как сделать такой цикл который будет игнорировать ошибку используемого файла

Извольте. По моему, простой и понятной демонстрацией будет такая. (Этот код - не без греха, например, я не анализирую причину Exception при удалении файлов. А может, там exception по причине слишком длинного имени. Но от него уже можно отталкиваться)

Также, обратите внимание, что если у вас папка открыта или какой то из файлов где то открыт (Word, notepad и т.п.) - может не удалиться.

> Мне не совсем понятен код, но буду разбираться.

Думаю, смогу минимально прокомментировать:
Класс Deleter - инкапсулирует функцию "удаление файлов из директории" (взял для примера, просто чтобы не возиться со списками файлов).
У этого класса один публичный метод. Метод возвращает true только если в процессе удаления не возникло ошибок.

Подсчет ошибок при удалении происходит так: в try{} мы говорим "удалить!", и если файл удалился - блок catch{} не исполняется.

Если же возникла ошибка - происходит вызов catch{}, и счетчик ошибок увеличивается на единицу.

В main'е просто создаётся экземпляр класса, и вызывается его метод. в цикле. с задержкой.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace Question
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const string testPath = @"C:\Temp\Logs";
                Deleter deleter = new Deleter();
                bool result = false;
                do{
                    result = deleter.DeleteFolder(testPath);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                } while (!result);

                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            }
        }

        class Deleter{
            public bool DeleteFolder( string folderName ){
                int errCouunter=0;
                foreach( var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName) ){
                    try{
                        File.Delete(file);
                    }
                    catch( Exception ex ){
                        errCouunter++;
                    }
                }
                return errCouunter==0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ваш первый способ мне подходит, но я не понимаю как сделать такой цикл который будет игнорировать ошибку используемого файла.

Comment: Вот как раз насчет удаления я бы не стал волновться. Гораздо интереснее, как сделана отправка. Там естьт простор для фантазии: например, модет ыбть асинхронная отправка, когад вызов метода Send просто говорит системе "ну, я тебе что сделать - сказал,  теперь ты не спеша отправляй". В большинстве случаев, при этом можно подписаться на событие "отправлено, хозяин!"

Comment: Отправка сделана простым способом с использованием библиотек System.Net и System.Net.Mail, при использовании smtp сервера и простого создания письма MailMessage.

Comment: Мне не совсем понятен код, но буду разбираться. Большое спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарии.

Comment: Если ответ Вам помог - Вы можете его "плюсануть" и/или принять (зеленая галочка рядом с числом голосов).